# Como trabalhar com Datas em C?

Tags: c, data

Fala ai seus pessoal! Peguei uma questão aqui na internet para fazer que não sai nada de forma alguma. Ele pede o seguinte: Deseja fazer um programa que leia o nome do livro que será emprestado, o tipo de
usuário (professor ou aluno) e a data de empréstimo do livro. O programa deve considerar que o
professor tem dez dias para devolver o livro e o aluno somente cinco dias. Caso algum deles devolva com
atraso, o programa deverá calcular a multa referente a esse atraso considerando o valor de R$ 0,50 por
dia de atraso. O programa deverá ler a data efetiva da devolução e ao final da execução, deverá imprimir
um recibo conforme mostrado abaixo:

Nome do livro: XXXXX

Tipo de usuário: XXXXX

Data do empréstimo: XX/XX/XXXX

Data prevista da devolução: XX/XX/XXXX

Data da devolução: XX/XX/XXXX

Multa por atraso: R$ XXX,XX

-Nome do livro:
-Tipo do usuário:
-Data do empréstimo:
-Data prevista de devolução:
-Data da devolução:
-Multa por atraso:

Meu problema maior são com as datas, pois não sei operar com elas.

```
#include<time.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<locale.h>

int main(){
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "portuguese");
    char usuario[10], livro[30];
    int dia, mes, ano;

        printf("Insira o nome do livro: ");
        scanf("%s", &livro);
        printf("Insira o tipo do usuário: ");
        scanf("%s", &usuario);
        printf("Insira a data do emprestimo: ");
        scanf("%d%*c%d*c%d", &dia, &mes, &ano);



            if((usuario[0]=='A')&&(usuario[1]=='L')&&(usuario[2]=='U'))
            {
            Nessa função "if" eu iria colocar um for para contar os dias de 
            atraso entre data de emprestimo e data da devolução, por exemplo:          

            dataemp=dataemp+5 //Pois alunos tem 5 dias para devolver    
            for(i = 0; dataemp<=datadev; i++)
            multa = i * 0.50;


            }
            if((usuario[0]=='P')&&(usuario[0]=='R')&&(usuario[0]=='O'))
            {

            dataemp=dataemp+10 //Pois professor tem 10 dias para devolver    
            for(i = 0; dataemp<=datadev; i++)
            multa = i * 0.50;

            }


}
```

Como posso pegar a data do usuário, subtrair essas datas, e acrescentar dias na data inserida pelo usuário? Já li sobre time.h mas não entendi bem ela a ponto de implementar meu código com ela. Ta foda, sério, 4 dias tentando fazer isso e não passo do algoritmo que escrevi acima.

Comment: Aliás, nas linhas da forma `dataemp=dataemp+`xxx, você esqueceu do ponto-e-vírgula no final; dentro do primeiro `if` tem um comentário sem os marcadores `//` ou `/* */`; e você geralmente quer fazer comparação de strings usando `strcmp()` ou `strncmp()`, assim: `if (!strncmp(usuario, "ALU", 3))`

Answer (score 1):

No C, não existem datas propriamente ditas. O tipo que faz as vezes de data no C é na verdade um `int` que conta *o número de segundos decorridos desde 1º de janeiro de 1970 UTC e a data em questão*. Mas para analisar sintaticamente uma data do tipo `DD/MM/YYYY`, você tem que usar outro tipo e outra função do `<time.h>`, que é a [`mktime()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/mktime/).

A `mktime()` recebe uma estrutura tipo [`struct tm`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/tm/) e retorna o `time_t` correspondente:

```
time_t
ler_data(const char data[11]) {
    struct tm tm = { 0 }; /* zera a struct toda */

    if (sscanf(data, "%d/%d/%d", &tm.tm_mday, &tm.tm_mon, &tm.tm_year) < 3) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Erro de formatação ao ler data %s\n", data);
        exit(1);
    }
    tm.tm_mon --; /* tm.mon espera o número de meses desde janeiro (0–11) */
    tm.tm_year -= 1900; /* tm.year espera o número de anos desde 1900 */

    return mktime(&tm);
}
```

Tendo isto, a diferença entre datas `A` e `B` em dias é `(B - A) / 86400`, visto que há 24 × 60 × 60 = 86.400 segundos em um dia. Aliás é melhor fazer `#define SEGUNDOS_EM_UM_DIA 86400` e depois dizer `(B - A) / SEGUNDOS_EM_UM_DIA`. Igualmente, para somar `n` dias a uma data `A` você faz `A + n * SEGUNDOS_EM_UM_DIA`.

Para fazer o caminho inverso, você vai ter que escrever a data em um buffer usando [`localtime()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/localtime/) para converter `time_t` em `struct tm` e depois [`strftime()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/strftime/) ou [`snprintf()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/snprintf/) para converter o `struct tm` em string:

```
void
escrever_data(char * buf, size_t len, time_t data) {
    struct tm * tm = localtime(&data);
    buf[0] = '\0';
    if (snprintf(buf, len, "%02d/%02d/%04d",
                           tm->tm_mday,
                           tm->tm_mon + 1,
                           tm->tm_year + 1900) < 10) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Erro de formatação ao escrever data 0x%08X\n", data);
        exit(1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Obrigado @Wtrmute me deu um horizonte, vou tentar fazer aqui a atividade!